# Redis Data Modeling for Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: spring, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

Looking at the link - [how to have relations many to many in redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907942/how-to-have-relations-many-to-many-in-redis). I tried to model this using Spring Data Redis `HashRedis` class. This example model....

```
# Here are my categories
> hmset category:1 name cinema  ... more fields ...
> hmset category:2 name music   ... more fields ...
> hmset category:3 name sports  ... more fields ...
> hmset category:4 name nature  ... more fields ...

# Here are my users
> hmset user:1 name Jack   ... more fields ...
> hmset user:2 name John   ... more fields ...
> hmset user:3 name Julia  ... more fields ...

# Let's establish the many-to-many relationship
# Jack likes cinema and sports
# John likes music and nature
# Julia likes cinema, music and nature

# For each category, we keep a set of reference on the users
> sadd category:1:users 1 3
> sadd category:2:users 2 3
> sadd category:3:users 1
> sadd category:4:users 2 3

# For each user, we keep a set of reference on the categories
> sadd user:1:categories 1 3
> sadd user:2:categories 2 4
> sadd user:3:categories 1 2 4
```

Once we have this data structure, it is easy to query it using the set algebra:

## Categories of Julia

```
> smembers user:3:categories
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "4"

# Users interested by music
> smembers category:2:users
1) "2"
2) "3"

# Users interested by both music and cinema
> sinter category:1:users category:2:users
1) "3"
```

User.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RedisHash("users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String emailId;
    private List<Category> categories;
}
```

Category.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RedisHash("category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private String categoryId;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    private List<User> users;
}
```

RedisExampleBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RedisExampleBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisExampleBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {  

        User jack = User.builder().firstName("Jack").emailId("jack@gmail.com").build();
        User john = User.builder().firstName("John").emailId("john@gmail.com").build();
        User julia  = User.builder().firstName("Julia ").emailId("julia @gmail.com").build();

        Category cinema = Category.builder().name("Cinema").type("Entertainment").users(Arrays.asList(jack, julia)).build();
        Category sports = Category.builder().name("Sports").type("Play Game").users(Arrays.asList(jack)).build();

        Category music = Category.builder().name("Music").type("Sounds").users(Arrays.asList(john, julia)).build();
        Category nature = Category.builder().name("Nature").type("Wild Life").users(Arrays.asList(john, julia)).build();

        categoryRepository.save(cinema);
        categoryRepository.save(sports);
        categoryRepository.save(music);
        categoryRepository.save(nature);



        Category myCinema = Category.builder().name("Cinema").name("Entertainment").build();
        Category mySport = Category.builder().name("Sports").name("Play Game").build();
        Category myMusic = Category.builder().name("Music").name("Sound").build();
        Category myNature = Category.builder().name("Nature").name("Wild Life").build();


        User myJack = User.builder().firstName("Jack").emailId("jack@gmail.com").categories(Arrays.asList(myCinema, mySport)).build();
        User myJohn = User.builder().firstName("John").emailId("john@gmail.com").categories(Arrays.asList(myMusic, myNature)).build();
        User myJulia  = User.builder().firstName("Julia ").emailId("julia @gmail.com").categories(Arrays.asList(myCinema,myMusic, myNature)).build();

        userRepository.save(myJack);
        userRepository.save(myJohn);
        userRepository.save(myJulia);
    }
}
```

Here is the result of Data Modeling

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "category:0bcba339-9a3e-46e3-b33c-877f8d15595f"
2) "category:4d2b8d10-83de-41fa-8a33-93f30a6f9ffc"
3) "category:f756f18c-53e4-4a20-9a42-ad08b537f380"
4) "category"
5) "users:644d0adc-f0cf-4ba1-8d6b-d6f47145e5e7"
6) "users:8aa5c578-4e05-4ae9-8f80-d10b789e0877"
7) "users:825ab11b-803a-4e4f-a72d-e6b42b98007c"
8) "category:54a56102-5836-41bf-86a8-c82b3f12d3cf"
9) "users"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I've not used `@Indexed` anywhere, because currently I am not using any `findBy` method, but thats not the issue. I just need confirmation on how to model the data? Or POJO modelling is correct ?

> HGETALL users:8aa5c578-4e05-4ae9-8f80-d10b789e0877

```
userId 8aa5c578-4e05-4ae9-8f80-d10b789e0877
_class com.example.model.User
firstName Jack
emailId jack@gmail.com
categories.[1].name Play Game
categories.[0].name Entertainment
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved this. You just maintain relationship into separate `@RedishHash` class and give `PK` (There is not `PK` in `Redis`, but meant to say `unique key`) and use PK from Category and PK from User and annotated them with `@Indexed`, so that you can do custom search using `Repository` pattern.

In this way, you're just maintaining the list of `Categories` for single `User` and also maintain `Users` for Single `category`. Just used single mapping here.

Like when saving data for `Category`, save `user` for that `Category`. **For example** - Assuming `User-1` interested in `Category-1`, `User-2` interested in `Category-1 and 2` and `User-3` interested in

```
Category-3
Category-1 save User-1
Category-1 save User-2

Category-2 save User-2
Category-2 save User-3
```

Done !! This works nicely. This is another approach simply using `CRUDRepository` patterns and without `RedisTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the another answer on the same link. As I've not received any comments from any of the expert yet. I will be so helpful if anyone does so.

I kept the model class as simple as that and just created a key to save the relationship between them. I need guidance from the Redis expert folks how to go ahead with the same.

This is very simple and I supposed what commands are doing, we're also doing the same.

```
// Category Details
Category c1 = Category.builder().id("c1").name("Cinema").build();
Category c2 = Category.builder().id("c2").name("Sports").build();
Category c3 = Category.builder().id("c3").name("Music").build();
Category c4 = Category.builder().id("c4").name("Nature").build();

redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:1", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(c1));
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:2", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(c2));
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:3", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(c3));
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:4", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(c4));

// User 
User u1 = User.builder().id("u1").firstName("Chris").emailId("chris.rogers@gmail.com").build(); //1
User u2 = User.builder().id("u2").firstName("John").emailId("john.doe@gmail.com").build();  //2
User u3 = User.builder().id("u3").firstName("Julia").emailId("julia.cox@gmail.com").build(); //3

redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("user:1", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(u1));
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("user:2", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(u2));
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("user:3", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(u3));

redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:1:users", "1","3");
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:2:users", "2","3");
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:3:users", "1");
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("category:4:users", "2","3");

redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("user:1:categories", "1","3");
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("user:2:categories", "2", "4" );
redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("user:3:categories", "1", "2", "4");
```

[image]

**Note: You can manage keys dynamically using `UUID`.**