# Redis design data structure based on secondary indices

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Let's say I have to store the following object in my cache-

```
{
    student_id: "student123",
    school_id: "xyz123",
    class_id: "class123"
}
```

How do I design my Redis data structure in a way where I can retrieve the object by any of the ids? 
I tried doing a `HSET` command: `HSET student123 school_id xyz123 class_id class123` but this creates a hash for the specific student_id. I also want to make sure that the search is in O(1). Thanks in advance!

To clarify, if I have to search by school_id, how would i go about that?

Comment: Hey, Can you share code as well what things you tried or links which you refer to get more clear ideas about solutions you have applied

Comment: I was referring to- https://redis.io/commands/hset

Comment: What is the problem you're having? You can't retrieve data by respective id? Search isn't O(1)? Both? Clarify your question.

Comment: just edited my comment @sazzad

Comment: HGETALL/HGET/HMGET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use multiple keys indexes to get O(1) in your queries.

Consider using other data structures as well. Take a look at [Secondary indexing with Redis](https://redis.io/topics/indexes),  [how to have relations many to many in redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907942/how-to-have-relations-many-to-many-in-redis) and this other [article on many to many](http://panuoksala.blogspot.com/2015/09/redis-many-to-many.html).

Say, using *sets*, you add the {student123, xyz456, class789} entry as:

```
SADD student:student123 "xyz456 class789"
SADD school:xyz456 "student123 class789"
SADD class:class789 "xyz456 student123"
```

You may think "this will increase my memory usage a lot". It does indeed. It is the usual trade-off between memory and processing. Relational databases also do this when creating indexes. But Redis will give you sub-millisecond performance, and Redis uses multiple tricks to optimize memory usage, like [ziplists](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/), see https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization.

What mix of data structures is best depends on the specifics of your use-case.

Consider removing the prefix in your keys if they are constant, just be consistent on the order you place them in the value.

```
SADD student:123 "456 789"
```

Keep in mind that sets and sorted sets allow unique members only. If you use one sorted set for students using student ID as score: `ZADD students 123 "456 789"`, and then add another student at the same school-class with `ZADD students 235 "456 789"` this actually updated the score for `"456 789"`, it didn't add a new value.